# how to use telerik silverlight controls in asp.net web application?

Tags: controls, telerik

i was using silverlight telerik controls,how to use them in my asp.net application as i am not getting them on the tool box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got your Silverlight content built out already, you can add that content to any standard ASP.NET page - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135987.aspx for details.  What @maple_shaft is referring to is Telerik's actual ASP.NET control suite (RadControls, etc.), which you would use if you wanted to build some ASP.NET applications using those controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Telerik offers a seperate control suite for asp.NET web applications however they require a seperate license.

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post from the Telerik support forum: [Adding RadControls to the Visual Studio 2010 Toolbox](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-adding-to-vs-toolbox-net4.html)

Comment: He mentions that he's using the Telerik Silverlight controls ([http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight.aspx](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight.aspx)), not the ASP.NET controls.

Comment: exactly,i had used silverlight controls already. i had hears that we use reference to silverlight xap file in asp.net web page to use those controls.